# Use ng-show along with ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, frontend

I am trying to loop through an array of objects and display the data only if the object has value for some key. Can I do the following?

```
<div ng-repeat = "stuff in Stuffs" ng-show = "stuff['foo']=='bar'">
  blah
</div>
```

Comment: Stuffs is an array of objects?

Comment: @BillP Yes it is an array of objects.

Comment: Both `ng-show` and `ng-if` work with `ng-repeat`. It is more efficient to use a filter in the `ng-repeat` expression. Why are you asking? Did you try it and have a problem? Or are you asking just for a reference?

Comment: @georgeawg I am a newbie in the frontend world. I tried it and it did not work for my project. I just tried this in some playground and it indeed worked. Basically I am checking my understanding of AngularJS's directives...

Comment: @georgeawg by using a filter did you mean using ng-if?

Comment: To help you with the problem in your project, we need an example that reproduces the problem. The example as shown will work. Using filter is more efficient. i.e. `ng-repeat="stuff in stuffArr | filter : myFilter"`. For more information, see [AngularJS  filter Filter API Reference - Examples](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter#examples)

Answer (score 3):

I think you are better off using a filter with the `ngRepeat` directive.

```
<div ng-repeat="stuff in Stuffs | filter:'bar'">
 {{stuff.foo}}    
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, using the filter technique is more efficient because the `ng-repeat` directive only builds the DOM that is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it like you wrote it. Both `ng-if` and `ng-show` will work:

```
<div ng-repeat="stuff in Stuffs" ng-if="stuff.foo == 'bar'">
  blah
</div>
```

Comment: Why use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to grab the key from the repeat like such:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
    <span>{{key}}<input type="text" ng-model="data[key]"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Essentially I want to filter out a line/row if stuff['foo'] is not 'bar', can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

ng-if should do the trick for you:

```
<div ng-repeat = "stuff in Stuffs" ng-if="your_expression">
  blah
</div>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-if.asp